# Iterating over parameter list when too many arguments in KSH

Tags: shell, parameters, ksh

Sometimes I have to iterate over all the files in a directory to find something and for that the usual `for i in $(ls *.txt)` would generally work. But there are cases when you have too many files in the folder and `for` yields `0403-027 The parameter list is too long.` (that is, `for`, `diff`, `ls`, or whatever).

I have found one solution for that is reading the input line by line with a `while read` but then it comes the tricky part. At first, I thought the ideal would be something like:

```
while read file ; do
    # do something with file
done < $(find . -type f -name *.txt)
```

But that returns a single line, filled with `^J` as separators (weird?) and, of course there will be no such file. Changing `IFS` to `\n` didn't work either.

My current workaround is building a temporary file with all the files I'm interested in and then using the while:

```
tmpfile=$$.$(date +'%Y%m%d%k%M%S').tmp
find . -type f -name *.txt > $tmpfile
while read file ; do
    # do something with file
done < $tmpfile ; rm $tmpfile
```

But that doesn't feels right, and so much more code than the first option.
Could someone tell me the right way to execute the first loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **process substitution**, not *command* substitution in this situation:

```
while IFS= read -r file ; do
    # do something with file
done < <(find . -type f -name *.txt)
```

A `<()` process substitution basically acts like a file, which you can redirect into the while-loop.

Comment: Hm.. that's exactly what documentation says as well, but by terminal says `0403-057 Syntax error: '(' is not expected.` This should work in ksh93 right? (I'm running a AIX box)

Comment: Gosh darn it.. I might have felt to this old version version issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=572024 to the sys admin!